# Proving that the uniformly distributed stopping time doesnt have the memoryless property

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Consider a chain which is not Markov that waits a time $T^{*}$ before leaving the current state, where $T^{*}$ has uniform distribution over the set of times $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ . I would like to show that it does not hold the memoryless property, i.e: $$\Bbb P(T \gt t+s \mid T \gt t)= \Bbb P(T \gt s)$$

So, here's how I tackle the problem:

I deduce that $T^{*}\sim\mathcal U\{1,4\}$ (discretely uniformly distributed on the interval $[1,4]$. So, the support is $x\in \{1,2,3,4\}$

The cumulative distribution function is:

$$\text{CDF}= \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor - 1+1}{4} = \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{4}= \Bbb P(T \leq x)$$

$$\Rightarrow 1- \text{CDF} = \Bbb P(T \geq x)= 1- \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{4}= \frac{4-\lfloor x \rfloor}{4}$$

$$\Rightarrow \Bbb P(T \geq s+t | T \geq t)= \frac{\Bbb P(T\geq s+t ; T\geq t)}{\Bbb P(T \geq t)}= \frac{\Bbb P(T \geq s+t)}{\Bbb P(T \geq t)} = \frac{\frac{4- \lfloor s+t \rfloor}{4}}{\frac{4- \lfloor t \rfloor}{4}}= \frac{4 - \lfloor s+t \rfloor}{4 - \lfloor t \rfloor} \neq \Bbb P(T\geq s) = \frac{4- \lfloor s \rfloor}{4}$$
Hence $T^{*}$ does not hold the memoryless property

Is this alright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to establish that uniform waiting times do not have the memorylessness property is by constructing a specific counter example.

So for your example of $\text{U}\left\{1,\ldots, 4\right\}$ let us choose $s = 1$ and $t = 3$ then we have on the left hand side

$$\mathbf P(T > 3 + 1 | T > 3) =  \mathbf P(T > 4 | T > 3) = 0,$$
whilst the right hand side is
$$\mathbf P(T > 1) = \frac14. $$

That is we've found a counter example to the statement that $\mathbf P(T > t + s| T> t) = \mathbf P(T > s)$.

---

**Further Context**

More generally you can prove that the only distributions to have the memorylessness property are exponential distributions (in the continuous case) and geometric distributions (in the discrete case).

Proofs for this can be found in Feller's *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications Vol. 1*, (refs. for 3rd edition: p.458 for exponential, and 329 for discrete)